# Custom Labels Translations not working in Lightning Flows

Tags: customlabel, visual-flows, lightning-flow-builder, custom-notification

I am using a flow to send custom notifications to the end user. I invoke a subflow that I created for Custom Notifications from Record Triggered flow and pass Notification Title and Body as a Custom Label in the flow variables so that it can be translated for different users.But it seems the Custom labels are not getting translated.I wasn't able to find anything related to it, so wondering, is it a limitation or this is as expected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue today. Fix for me was putting custom labels into text formula variable that just has the label inside of it.